# Individual elements of a list within a function

Tags: python

I have created a list that holds 45 names. Now i would like to create a loop that calls each name individually within a function ("Has name 1 paid? If yes then next name, if no then remove name from list then next name") I am fairly new to python :/ I would appreciate you if you gave me examples rather than simply answering the question.
Thank you

```
#Task 2

name_list = []
count = 0
name = "empty"
while count < 45:
   name == raw_input("Enter the student's name")
   name_list.append(name)
   count = count + 1 

print "List full"

# Where do I go from here?
```

Comment: So what was your attempt? Do you know about `for` loops? It's unclear what your exact problem is

Comment: Have a look at the official [Python Tutorial - Lists](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: I don't think you mean `==` there.

Answer (score 2):

```
for student in name_list:
     if(input("Have the student " + student + " paid?") != "yes"):
         name_list.remove[student]
```

Comment: Those are some really strange parenthesis, for Python code.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['abc',
       'xyz',
       'lmn',
       'pqr']
```

for loop in python can be used similar to foreach in php
 for in python doesn't require size of the list to be specified

```
for el in arr:
    ## here we can iterate through all elements in arr
    ## here el an element in arr for that perticular iteration
    print el
```

In your case
 let arr be list of all names you have
 len gives the length of an iterable in this case list

```
i = 0
while i < len(arr):
    user_input = raw_input("Have the student " + arr[i] + " paid?")
    ## raw_input returns user input in string format
    if 'yes' != user_input:
        arr.remove(arr[i])
        ## removes function removes the specified element from the list
        i -= 1
        ## decrements index by 1 so as to get the next element from the array
    i += 1
```

here using for will cause some problem because removing an element entirely from a list changes its index and making some elements in the list to skip